# Google sheet and Appsheet Inventory App: Logic for Logging in remaining stock instead of recording one item sold at a time. App to determine sales

Tags: google-sheets

I need to develop logic for an Inventory Management app for a small business using google sheet and appsheet.

The app to allow recording of remaining stock everyday morning and any additional stock that comes in, the app to internally determines sales made the previous day and keep a record of this day after another.
In a small retail shop, it is convenient to count remaining stock every morning rather than recording every sale every time during the day.

Unlike other POS systems where each items are scanned or recorded one by one as they are being sold, I want to just record the remaining stock and additional stock, the app to do the rest.

Here is a google drive link to the folder containing the google sheet and product images.

[Google drive folder](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zjbH3M0j2XRyEpQf53ugCPMSagStFsw5?usp=sharing)

The spreadsheet contains 3 sheets:

1. Stock list: Contains products available in the store and their prices.
2. Stock Review: Used for logging remaining stock every morning. Currently contains remaining stock logged for 30th 31th May 2022
3. Add Stock: For logging in additional stock

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: This sounds like a logistics problem, not a spreadsheet problem. Can you describe in words how you would accomplish your goals say… on paper? It reminds me of double-entry inventory systems, where sales are logged, but also actions like purchasing, restocking, and correction entries after taking an inventory. If that take is off the mark and you've hit an answerable, technical problem in Sheets, please edit your question to include details on that.

Comment: I have edited my questions to include details and link to the app for your assistance

Comment: The AppSheet is not accessible. Please provide a sample sheet (or make the AppSheet accessible), and what is your expected output. Read the [How to Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before updating your question.

Comment: @Emel I have made edit to my question and provided a link to the sample sheet

Comment: You can review [this](https://support.google.com/appsheet/answer/11997142?hl=en) in order to call Apps Script from an automation of Appsheet, you just need to build a script to accomplish what you need.